# MongoDB bulk insert failing for array of strings

Tags: mongodb

Given the following array:

```
arr = ["{'myId': 'myVal1'}","{'myId': 'myVal2'}"]
```

I can insert the items one by one, e.g.

```
db.collection.insert(arr[0])
```

But it fails when I try to insert the whole array (like it says in http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/ )

```
db.collection.insert(arr)
Error: not an object src/mongo/shell/collection.js:179
```

I'm using MongoDB 2.2.4

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to insert an array of strings - mongo expects an array of json documents.

`"{'foo':'bar'}"` is a string.
`{'foo':'bar'}` is an object - a json document with one key value pair.

It looks to you like the insert is succeeding when you do

`db.collection.insert("{'foo':'bar'}")` but it's not doing what you think it is.

```
> db.collection.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("51941c94c12b0a7bbd416430"),
    "0" : "{",
    "1" : "'",
    "2" : "f",
    "3" : "o",
    "4" : "o",
    "5" : "'",
    "6" : ":",
    "7" : "'",
    "8" : "b",
    "9" : "a",
    "10" : "r",
    "11" : "'",
    "12" : "}",
    "trim" : function __cf__12__f__anonymous_function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
},
    "ltrim" : function __cf__13__f__anonymous_function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+/, "");
},
    "rtrim" : function __cf__14__f__anonymous_function() {
    return this.replace(/\s+$/, "");
},
    "startsWith" : function __cf__15__f__anonymous_function(str) {
    return this.indexOf(str) == 0;
},
    "endsWith" : function __cf__16__f__anonymous_function(str) {
    return (new RegExp(RegExp.escape(str) + "$")).test(this);
}
}
```

I already put a pointer to [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object) in your other question which asks how to convert this string.